# Is there a way to get arround instagram bot dedector

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, tracking

I tried to write an automatic program with python and selenium to create automated Instagram accounts.  I have added all security options and even Instagram prevents me from creating new accounts.

I literally tried everything. Cleaning cookies, catch, incognito-mode, proxy, disabled location, used fake headers and at last I tried a new internet connection (Hotspot by my smartphone). But Instagram still blocks me. How can I modify my code to prevent Instagram me from being detected as me?

The InstaAction class only calls storage.clear()

```
class MyInstaAction(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__('chromedriver.exe', *args, **kwargs)

    def root(self):
        self.get(mpaths.root)

    def create_account(self, user):
        self.get(mpaths.register)
        self.execute_script('localStorage.clear();')

        # Finding elements and doing other stuff
```

"Main" securety settings

```
    if mconf.use_proxy:
        proxies = my_proxys.get_proxys()

        if count > len(proxies):
            print(f'Only {len(proxies)} available\n'
                  f'Setting counter to maximum of {len(proxies)}')
            count = len(proxies)
    else:
        proxies = [0 for _ in range(count)]

    for i, proxy in zip(range(count), proxies):
        try:
            user = MyUserFactory.get_user()
            if doc.does_user_exist(user):
                same += 1
                continue

            opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            opt.add_argument("disable-infobars")
            opt.add_argument("--incognito")
            prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2}
            opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
            ua = rua.random
            print(ua)
            opt.add_argument(f"user-agent={ua}")
            opt.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
            if proxy:
                # Setting up proxy package
                opt.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)

            # end
            iact = MyInstaAction(options=opt)
            iact.delete_all_cookies()
```

Does anybody how to get around this problem?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Well first of all you shouldn't be trying to get around the bot-detector; it is there for a reason, and second, it is a very strong bot detector, probably built to be unpassable, so you will almost certainly fail everytime

Comment: "I literally tried everything." - well then it directly follows that it's not possible.

Comment: @apatrck00 How is Instagram **blocking** you? _reCaptcha_ challenge or _Access Denied_ message?

Comment: @DebanjanB   Dont know?  I have added an image. Hop it helps. Thanks for commend (-:

Comment: @apatrck00 Not sure about the language can you help us with the English translation of the error text?

Comment: @DebanjanB For sure. The read text means: What a pity, while creating your account an error occurred. Please try again after a short time.

Comment: same issue here bro

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the user-agent.
`options.add_argument("user-agent=YOUR_DEVICE")`

Comment: I have done this for every new account I have created. With this line: 
```opt.add_argument(f"user-agent={ua}")```
I found a library which randomly creates valid user-agents, but this doesn’t help. 
But thanks for help. (-: